# How to make argparse require argument name but remain optional with no prefix?

Tags: python, argparse

This is what I have -

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--foo", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--bar", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I want to not have the `--` (or any) prefix. I can simply remove it from `--role` and `--bar` names(renaming them to `role` and `bar`), but that won't allow me to enable the `required` parameter.

I need to have the `required` parameter of `add_arguments()` set to `True` because I want to make the argument name compulsory before the argument.

My goal is to make only these (and no other syntax) -

```
my_script.py foo=fooval bar=barval
my_script.py foo=fooval
my_script.py bar=barval
my_script.py bar=barval foo=fooval
my_script.py
```

valid.

Comment: Don't use `argparse` it you don't want to use its syntax.  The distinction between `positional` and `optional/flagged` arguments is built in to `argparse`.  If you don't like, it use something else.

Comment: I don’t think what you want (not having the — on bar and foo but requiring foo= and bar=) is possible using argparse. Argparse will also always allow the alternative `—foo foovalue —bar barvalue`

Comment: People have asked for parsers that handle generic `key=value` inputs. That's possible - just accept `postional` stirngs, and split them yourself.  Or do the same with the `sys.argv` list.

Comment: Is your goal just to parse ``foo=fooval`` and similar from the command line? Should ``my_script.py foo fooval`` be allowed? Do you actually need argparse for its other features?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I edited the question to clarify my desired valid syntax. And no, I do not need argparse for its other features.  

I decided to use argparse because it is a Python builtin library and has a relatively simple syntax. (But from the other comments, it seems like argparse does not allow my particular use case)

Comment: @PratyushDas Turns out this is actually easily doable by preprocessing, *if* there are either no positional or flag parameters. Check out my answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying `argparse` to handle other formats is technically possible, but requires a huge effort. It is easier to build a custom argument parser, especially if one does not need many features. However, it is easy to pre-process arguments and use `argparse` as a backend.

The basis for CLI arguments is `sys.argv`. For example, executing `my_script.py bar=barval foo=fooval` sets `sys.argv` to `['my_script.py', 'foo=12', 'bar=13']`. This can be pre-processed for use with `argparse` or entirely manually processed. Which of these is preferable depends on how much functionality of `argparse` is desired.

---

For use with `argparse`, one needs to:

- emulate the help messages,
- adjust supplied arguments.

Both can be achieved by using a `prefix_chars=' '` – `argparse` renders this as if no prefix were used, and it can be explicitly added to arguments.

```py
import sys
import argparse

# parser with "invisible" prefix
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars=' ')
parser.add_argument(" foo")
parser.add_argument(" bar")
# arguments with prefix added
argv = [
    (' ' + item) if item[0] != ' ' else item
    for item in sys.argv[1:]
]
# parse pre-processed arguments
args = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

Depending on whether both positional arguments and flags must be supported, additional pre-processing might be required.

---

A simple parser for the desired format looks like this:

```py
def parse_args(__argv__=None, **options):
    """Parse command line arguments"""
    argv = sys.argv if __argv__ is None else __argv__
    # split leading `my_script.py` executable from `foo=12`, ... arguments
    executable, *arguments = argv
    for argument in arguments:
        # split each `name=value` pair
        name, value = argument.split('=')
        if name not in options:
            raise ValueError(f"Unknown option: {name}")
        options[name] = value
    return options
```

This allows to specify expected arguments and their default values via keywords.

```
>>> argv = ['my_script.py', 'foo=12', 'bar=13']
>>> parse_args(argv, foo=None, bar='17', qux='12')
{'foo': '12', 'bar': '13', 'qux': '12'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the required=True option. When you set required to true, it will always expect that argument to be passed in. But without that, it will expect a value anytime the prefix is provided.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--foo")
parser.add_argument("--bar")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Note: the above will allow `my_script.py` without any arguments. Arguments added without a prefix will be considered required by default.

Comment: This does not allow `my_script.py foo=fooval bar=barval`.

Comment: I don't think argparse will allow you to do that without adding the prefix